# How to implement GetResult[List[String]] in scala slick?

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I'm use SQLActionBuilder, such as `seq"""select ..."""`, to create a common/wide sql query and I not care about the result column count it is.
Document example use `as[TupleX]` to decided result type,in my stage, I want use `List[String]` replace `TupleX` type.
I have attempted with `sQLActionBuilder.as[List[String]]` but a compile error encounter:

```
Error:(8, 187) could not find implicit value for parameter rconv: slick.jdbc.GetResult[List[String]]
  val x = reportUtilRepository.find(List())("td_report_region")(1469635200000L, 1475251200000L)("region" :: Nil, "clicks" :: "CPC" :: Nil)(List("1", "2"), List("regionType" -> "1"))(_.as[List[String]]).map(x => println(x.toString))
```

and `sQLActionBuilder.as[List[(String, String, String)]]` works well. So how can I use `List[String]` to match a common result.

I think a straight way is implement a `GetResult[List[String]]` as compiler tips but I don't know how to do it.Other ways also welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

First of all querying database always returns a list of tuples, so the result type will be `List[TupleX]` because each row is represented as a list record and then columns in each row are respectively tuple elements.
Therefore, your data will look like `List((1,2,3),(3,4,5))` where data type is `List[(Int, Int, Int)]`. To produce `List[Int]` you might do following:

```
val a = List((1,2,3),(3,4,5))
a map {x => List(x._1, x._2, x._3)} flatten
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5)
```